# Using Property JS files in React Native

Tags: react-native

In React Native, you can have a separate file for styling and access that file from other pages to refer to the stylings.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
const Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var {
    StyleSheet,
    } = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    defaultBackground: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    },
    menuButton: {
        fontSize: 22,
        color: '#ffffff',
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1
    }
});

module.exports = styles;
```

Here this is acquired by "StyleSheet" of React.

Say for a sample like following,

```
myName: 'Username',
myURL: 'www.google.com',
reactNativeUser: true,
age: 22,
```

Something like this to be used in a separate file as a property file and to be used across the application.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Export plain object

You could export a plain object.
And create the stylesheet as necessary.

```
// style.js
export const Style = {
    defaultBackground: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    },
    menuButton: {
        fontSize: 22,
        color: '#ffffff',
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1
    }
}

// component.js
import React, {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Style as Globalstyle} from 'style'

var styles = StyleSheet.create(Globalstyle);
```

Maybe I understood your question not correctly. To export those constants you could use the same approach.

```
//propertyfile.js
export const myName = "Username";
export const myURL = "www.google.com",
export const reactNativeUser = true;
export const age = 22;

//component.js
import {myName, myURL, reactNativeUser, age} from 'propertyfile'
```

Comment: where we will be placing this file 'propertyfile.js' in project structure? it should work for ios and android right.

Comment: That’s up to you. Next to the component? Just leave out the suffix .ios or .android to use it cross-platform